# How to access vaue from Object

Tags: c#, object

I need access value from the object, My code as follows,

```
public class ValidationResult
{
    public string ErrorType { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public object AdditionalData { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I set value from Stoted procedure(please be noted, this part of my code)

```
public ValidationResult GetCustomer(int lobbyId, string serviceId)
{
    DataSet cusInfo = DataAccessManager.ExecuteStoredProcedure("spCustomerEntry", parameters.ToArray());
    ValidationResult valResult = new ValidationResult();
    valResult.AdditionalData = new
    {
        AppointmentData = cusInfo.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(accData => new { CosId = Convert.ToInt32(accData["CosId"]), CosRefNo = Convert.ToInt32(accData["CosRefNo"])})
    };
    return valResult;   
}
```

I'm calling this `GetCustomer` method from the another class, and need to get `CosId,CosRefNo` values. I'm trying to do it like this.But its make some error. How can I get `CosId`

```
ValidationResult validationResult = null;
validationResult = ltsLob.GetCustomer(lobbyId, serviceId);
var CosId = validationResult.AdditionalData.GetType().GetProperty("CosId").GetValue(validationResults.AdditionalData, null);
```

Comment: "ValidationResult" is your object and you are using it like its an array.You should directly access the "AdditionalData" property like this. validationResult.AdditionalData.

Comment: @VimalPatel I tried as it is, but same error occur

Comment: Any particular reason you are using "AdditionalData" property as Object? I recommended using a concreate class instead of Object.

Comment: @VimalPatelall currently other classes access it as object, So can't change it, please help me to access those data

Comment: Your SP can return multple resultset, Do you want to get all the records.Please mention your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GetCustomer method Replace existing code with below code. Only change I did is Added "ToList" method in the end.

```
valResult.AdditionalData = new
{   
    AppointmentData = dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(accData => new { CosId = Convert.ToInt32(accData["CosId"]), CosRefNo = Convert.ToInt32(accData["CosRefNo"])}).ToList()
};
```

And you can access data of that object like below.

```
var data = result.AdditionalData.GetType().GetProperty("AppointmentData").GetValue(result.AdditionalData, null);
foreach(var item in (IList)data) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Here is the fiddler.Try it out.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/RE7tvH

Comment: How can I assign value to variable inside loop. I tried as  `CosId = item[0]` , but it shows this error. `cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: when I debugging its like this. https://i.imgur.com/b8z7c3x.png . I added `item` into `ArrayLsit` object and trying get `ApointmentId,LobbyId` values. how can I do it

Comment: Don't add item directly into ArrayList, I have updated the above fiddle, please check.

Comment: how can I assign that value into long varaibe, I tried as `(long)item.GetType().GetProperty("CosId").GetValue(item,null);` But its makes run time error. invalid cast

Comment: Change the type in this line.
AppointmentData = dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(accData => new { CosId = Convert.ToInt64(accData["CosId"]), CosRefNo = Convert.ToInt64(accData["CosRefNo"])}).ToList()

Comment: While creating the type you mentioned int32 that's why it is throwing error.